# for loop to cbind and write.csv

Tags: csv, for-loop, extract

I am using mzR package to extract simple information from a .mzXML file using instrumentInfo(). It gives me a 1x5 matrix with the desired information. However, I want to do it to each file in an entire directory and output the information onto one .txt or .csv file. I was thinking of using a for loop however my R knowledge is limited. Please help, thanks for your time.

```
library("mzR")

file<-list.files("C:/Users/sktrinh", pattern="\\.mzXML$",full.names=T,recursive=T) 

    N<-length(file)
    for (i in 1:N) {
      ms<-openMSfile(file[i])
      file.1<-as.data.frame(instrumentInfo(ms))
      m <- cbind(file.1, path=file[i])[,c(6,1,2,3,4,5)]
    write.csv(m,"C:/Users/sktrinh/mzxml_output.csv")
```

Here is a link to a test .mzXML file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-COYPSEsQK7bjJRVFVyVFBiNkU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error I wrote a working script:

```
library("mzR")

file<-list.files("C:/Users/trinh/Downloads/", pattern="\\.mzXML$",full.names=T,recursive=T) 

mswrite<-function(z){
  ms<-openMSfile(z)
  f<-as.data.frame(instrumentInfo(ms))
  m<-cbind(f,path=z)[,c(6,1,2,3,4,5)]
}

d<-data.frame() #generate empty data.frame
N<-length(file) 
for (i in 1:N) {
  y<-mswrite(file[i])
  d<-rbind(d,y)
  }

write.csv(d,"C:/Users/trinh/Downloads/mzxml_output.csv")
```

If anyone can think of a better way to accomplish this, please chime in. Thanks.